AWS StepFunction startExecution adding :UUID to name
I'm trying to set the name of an Express StepFunction execution in a lambda so that the StepFunction prevents any duplicate processing.
This code works as expected, except somehow a colon followed by a random changing unrelated UUID is being appended to the end of the the name I'm setting. (I.e. we're setting it as 1234 and when it gets to the StepFunction it shows as 1234:550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000)
This prevents the StepFunction from filtering out requests with the same name, as is required.
const aws = require("aws-sdk");
const SFN_ARN = process.env.SFN_ARN;
const stepFunctions = new aws.StepFunctions({region: process.env.REGION_NAME});

function buildSFNParams(request) {
    let params = {
        "stateMachineArn": SFN_ARN,
        "input": JSON.stringify(request),
        "name": request.id
    };
    return params;
}

exports.executeAsync = async (request) => {
        let params = buildSFNParams(request);
        return await stepFunctions.startExecution(params).promise();
}    


Update: it looks like using a Standard StepFunction (instead of an Express) is behaving as expected. That said, the docs don't appear mention this functionality, although they do describe slightly different idempotency/concurrency behavior based on name. I'm thinking this is likely a bug on the aws side, or at least an undocumented side effect of that behavior.
